What SMP Packet is missing here for the BLE Pairing to finish successfully?
I am trying to perform a MitM-Attack for educational purposes on my own BLE Keyboard with help of this Framework:
Mirage (I modified this pull requests further for my own purposes though)
On the process of pairing with the keyboard however, it does work, but after 30s the Keyboard disconnects. I suspect this is because of the SMP Timeout specified in the Bluetooth Core Specs v5.3 page 1599.
My guess is that some SMP Packets that are necessary are not yet implemented and therefor the keyboard runs into the timeout.
Here is a list of the packages in the pairing so far: (C = central, P = peripheral(keyboard))

C->P  Connect Indication
C->P  Pairing Request
C<-P  Pairing Response
C->P  Sent Pairing Public Key
C<-P  Rcvd Pairing Public Key
C<-P  Rcvd Pairing Confirm
C->P  Sent Pairing Random
C<-P  Rcvd Pairing Random
C->P  Sent Pairing DHKey Check
C<-P  Rcvd Pairing DHKey Check
C->P  LL_ENC_REQ
C<-P  LL_ENC_RSP
C<-P  LL_START_ENC_REQ
C->P  ??? (can't see the rest, it's encrypted)

From the Mirage STD-out I can see the following part:
(full stdout can be found here)
[INFO]    [13:28:47.991667] Connecting to slave D5:BB:76:E9:2F:A9...
[SUCCESS] [13:28:48.191875] Connected on slave : D5:BB:76:E9:2F:A9
[INFO]    [13:28:48.192579] << BLE - Pairing Request Packet | outOfBand=no | inputOutputCapability=0x3 | authentication=0x1d | maxKeySize=16 | initiatorKeyDistribution=0x3 | responderKeyDistribution=0x3 >>
[SUCCESS] [13:28:48.195843] Started Advertising. Entering WAIT_CONNECTION stage ...
[INFO]    [13:28:48.366898] << BLE - Pairing Response Packet | outOfBand=no | inputOutputCapability=0x2 | authentication=0x1d | maxKeySize=16 | initiatorKeyDistribution=0x2 | responderKeyDistribution=0x3 >>
[INFO]    [13:28:48.378317] << BLE - Public Key Packet | key_x=b'B,\xe7\x99\xed\xbe\xdb%\x10Q,Cy\x06\x16\xd4\x14<\xf8S\xc20A\xe8\x96\xd1*\x84\xb1H\x1cH' | key_y=b'\x10-\x95\xcc\\\xc5\xe5\xcb\xb8\xa1\xbb\x01\xf4j\x97v,\xbb\xaaz\x9e\x8f\x05\x03\xe8\xfe#_A\xe0\xa6\x14' >>
[INFO]    [13:28:48.474534] << BLE - Public Key Packet | key_x=b'\x1a\x14\xf0\xc1\x01\xec\x91\xf6\xfaK\x98\xf6\x81\xee,p\x00\x0c\xc2P!/J\x9dR\x16@D\x83-EL' | key_y=b'_\xc7\x96_SH\x08\xe3^T\ri[|x\xab\xa3r\xdbV\xd9[k\xa7#d\x96\x86\xc4P\x1f\x05' >>
[SUCCESS] [13:28:48.477176] DH Key generated: 8c4a448b660d1b92fa16b9e3f76a0361906c1df5b6ec0e6d0731d554ab9f9430
[INFO]    [13:28:48.478190] << BLE - Pairing Confirm Packet | confirm=dccf1683f7e2858ffdfa16dc9409d500 >>
[INFO]    [13:28:48.567808] << BLE - Pairing Random Packet | random=b51af88ea19933dd2b0da06d2b51e684 >>
[INFO]    [13:28:48.568465] Slave verify Confirm value success!
[INFO]    [13:28:48.568536] Slave deriving LTK
[INFO]    [13:28:48.568913] MacKey: b'\xf3\xe3\xf3\xfe\xee\xeeB+M\x08\x0e\xa4AYt\xef'
[INFO]    [13:28:48.568951] LTK: b'$\x07\x13.}w\xebtJ\xf11\x13b\xab\xaa\xc3' of type <class 'bytes'>
[INFO]    [13:28:48.568973] Slave sending DH Key Check
[INFO]    [13:28:48.667564] << BLE - DH Key Check | dhkey_check=b'1m\xc1\x19S\x1b?\xb6\x19ln\x1fp\xb4\xdd\x8e' >>
[INFO]    [13:28:48.668536] Slave DH Key Check success!
[INFO]    [13:28:48.668577] Slave Try to encrypt link
[INFO]    [13:28:48.668618] To Slave: << BLE - HCI Start Encryption Request | rand=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' | ediv=0 | ltk=b'\xc3\xaa\xabb\x131\xf1Jt\xebw}.\x13\x07$' >>
[INFO]    [13:28:48.966662] From Slave: << BLE - HCI Encryption Change | status=0 | enabled=1 >>
[INFO]    [13:28:48.966706] Slave Encryption success
[INFO]    [13:28:49.016964] Identity Information (from slave) : irk = 70bfab1794b6b66f9b377632286aed52
[INFO]    From Slave: << BLE - Identity Address Information Packet | type=random | address=d5:bb:76:e9:2f:a9 >>
[INFO]    [13:28:49.067104] Sent IRK
[INFO]    [13:28:49.067176] Slave pairing finished
[INFO]    [13:28:49.117132] Connection Parameter Update Request (from slave) : slaveLatency = 20 / timeoutMult = 210 / minInterval = 16 / maxInterval = 20
[INFO]    [13:28:49.117221] Sending a response to slave ...

Since I think the Pairing Request and Pairing Response might be higly relevant for answering of this question, here are the packets sniffed with Sniffle and examined with Wireshark:
Pairing Request:

Pairing Response:

If you have any idea why this pairing won't "finish", please let me know

After encryption starts, based on the pairing request / response, the following packets shall be exchanged in this order:

IRK from peripheral
BDADDR from peripheral
IRK from central
BDADDR from central

When this is done, the pairing sequence is finished.
The packet sequence before encryption starts seems correct.
Tip: if you use Linux and HCI_CHANNEL_USER, you can use the btmon tool to monitor packets sent over HCI.

Okay thank you, I found out that those 4 packets have been successfully transmitted after doing some debugging. After this the peripheral sends an Connection Parameter Update Request, which I also answer. The keyboard still does terminate the connection after 30 seconds though... Can you think of any other reason why this might fail?

Maybe if you don't subscribe to the HID Report characteristics then it decides to disconnect after some time of inactivity?

Could be an Idea, I have edited my question to include a Link to the full Mirage stdout.
In there you can see that the keyboard disconnected shortly after [13:29:18.164503] while it connected on [13:28:48.191875], which would be almost exactly 30s. After the MitM paired to both sides, it just redirects every packet to the corresponding peer, including the Read by Type Request or the Read Requests. At the end you can see some Handle Value Notifications, which means that it has subscribed at some point. Maybe it disconnects because it isn't finished with discovering the GATT-suff or so?

Also another thing that I mentioned is that the keyboard sometimes needs up to half a second to responde (see time beween [13:29:02.433518] and[13:29:02.990710]). Maybe it also has something to do with that

Also what might also be worth mentioning, ist that when pairing the dongle with solaar and mirage as MitM in between, the pairing dialogue with the number to type in doesn't vanish. When I paired without Mirage as MitM in between, the dialogue did vanish after some seconds after typing the digits, and it didn't disconnect.
